# Swift: Thousand separator in localised strings using Localizable.stringsdict

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

I try to use Localizable.stringsdict to handle plurals in a swift app.

All works fine so far, but there are no thousand separators for big numbers. Is there any way to get a result like:

```
1 new Continent
1,000 new Continents
```

at the moment I get

```
1 new Continent
1000 new Continents
```

This is the begin of the Localizable.stringsdict file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>WNC_NewContinents</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%#@Variable@</string>
        <key>Variable</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>d</string>
            <key>zero</key>
            <string>%d new Continents</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string>%d new Continent</string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>%d new Continents</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

and this is the Swift code I use

```
   var bodyText: String = ""
   let item1 : Int = 1
   let item1000 : Int = 1_000

   let format = NSLocalizedString("WNC_NewContinents", comment: "")

   bodyText += String.localizedStringWithFormat(format, item1)
   bodyText += "\n"
   bodyText += String.localizedStringWithFormat(format, item1000)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
let s = String(format: format, locale: Locale.current, arguments: [item1000])
print(s) //1,000 new Continents
```

(*The locale does change number formatting.*)

Given the dictionary:

```
<dict>
    <key>WNC_NewContinents</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%#@variable@</string>
        <key>variable</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>d</string>
            <key>zero</key>
            <string>new Continents</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string>%d  new Continent</string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>%d new Continents</string>
        </dict>
</dict>
```

Here is what it gives in a playground:

[image: 1000]

Comment: well i tried that before, but this does not work together with the Localizable.stringsdict. If i understand the process well, the argument have to be numerical (no string allowed)

Comment: What do you mean by "*not work together with the Localizable.stringsdict*"?

Comment: Well somehow the methode needs an information about the arithmetic number to choose the right plural (there are up to 5 plurals per key). I tried to exchange the "d" and "%d" by "s" and "%s" and use a localised formate string of the integer (by number formatter) as an argument. But in that case, the variable "format" will be filled with "%#@Variable@" instead of "%d new Continents". So it simply can't choose the right plural and return the NSStringLocalizedFormatKey itself.

Comment: upps.. will try... ;-)

Comment: No, sorry, same result. I used this line of code to build the final string: "bodyText += String(format: format, locale: Locale.current, arguments: [item.notNotified])" ... item.notNotified is the Int I want to show. It is still without thousands separator. .. the solution works fine and has the expected outcome .. just the thousands separator is missing ;-)

Comment: In YOUR locale, is there a thousands separator?

Comment: @Hardy_Germany Could you print this in a playground: `Locale.current.groupingSeparator`

Comment: Yes, yes.. in Germany it the "." instead of the "," and vice versa for the decimals, so we write 1.000,00 for 1,000.00 ... but anyway, for the development I use the US settings as locale.. and it works on all other places in the app when I use formatted numbers. Just not with Localizable.stringsdict... there must be a way to do it ... I just have to look for it ... it is well hidden ;-)

Comment: import UIKit
var str = "Hello, playground"
print(Locale.current.groupingSeparator!) 
Output: ","
I'm not sure how playground get its local settings. In the simulator I use the schema settings .. and they are set to "english", region: United States (well "Vereinigte Staaten" but this is the German name of USA)

Comment: OOOOHHHHH I'm such an idiot! Your solution works perfectly! I always looked to the wrong output, which is still under construction and not formatted so far ... Sorry, Sorry for that ... I will accept your answer and hopefully nobody will see my stupid commentary ...

Comment: LOL, it's ok, we all have our moments ;)